# Is Wikipedia wrong about the Multinormal Distribution PDF

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

[image]

I was on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) page of Multivariate Normale Distribution and I was wondering if the PDF of the Multivariate Normale Distribution is right.
Shouldn't be: $(2\pi)^{(-k/2)}|\Sigma|^{-(1/2)}$ instead of $|2\pi\Sigma|^{-1/2}$ ?

Comment: No, it's correct. Because the $2\pi$ is inside the determinant, it is equivalent to $(2\pi)^{k/2}$ outside of the determinant sign.

Comment: Right, I've just checked the determinant properties. Thank you.